# Stopping an Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

If I stop an instance, I understand that I am not charged. However, I've installed several items on my machine in the last few hours (Mysql uploaded a db, Apache, PHP, etc...). I assume that when I stop the instance I retain these software installations, correct? Are these things stored in EBS? If so, where is the pricing listed for EBS, as I guess I will be charged every hour of every day for the whole year for my EBS storage given that it can never "stop"...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/, the current rates are:

- $0.10 per GB-month of provisioned storage
- $0.10 per 1 million I/O requests

Your data will persist if the root device is EBS backed, which is default now. You can check in the EC2 control panel.

So stopping the instance (if 8GB EBS) will cost about $0.80 per month for storage if it is never running.

Comment: nice. any command I can run in SSH to confirm that I'm backed up?

Comment: @Derek, Not sure. But from the AWS EC2 page, click on the instance, and look at the properties below. You want it to say: "Root Device Type: ebs". If it says "instance store" it won't persist. (Also, you'll see it listed under the EBS Volumes section.)

Comment: perfect, it says "Root Device Type: ebs". Thanks for your help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If your instance is EBS backed all data is safe. You will be charged for EBS storage only. Amazon EBS storage charged on per-month basis. Currently it's $0.10 per GB-month.